# What dropdown box does rails_admin use?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-admin

I want to use it in my rails projects instead of the default selectbox, but can't figure out what kind it is or how to implement it in my code.

The rails_admin one is more like a textbox with typeahead instead of just a standard dropdown.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they have created their own, here take a look:

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/rails_admin/ra.filtering-multiselect.js

It would be nice to pull it out and make a plugin, as a note it does look like it depends on jQuery, and jQueryUI.